# The OS Shell is not toggle-able in my GPS tools menu, How do I enable it?

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I'm new to Ada and I installed GPS. I'd like to see the OS Shell but it is grayed out. All I could find is that it has to do with a file shell.py, but I cannot find this anywhere in my GPS folder. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This might be specific to which OS, which OS version, and which GPS release you have.

Comment: GNAT GPL 2016 & macOS: in `$prefix/share/gps/plug-ins/`

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 and it's gnat-gpl-2016-x86-window-bin

Comment: Then you haven’t installed it, you’ve just unpacked the download package. There should be a README file in that directory with instructions how to install.

Answer (score 0):

What is grayed out exactly ? The menu /Tools/Consoles/OS Shell should never be grayed out, since it has no associated filter that would do that.
The contextual menu only works on directories (but then when you click elsewhere, the menu just isn't there, it is never grayed out either).